# What is the difference between advertising identifier and app instance id?

Tags: firebase-analytics, idfa

I use Firebase Analytics on a mobile app, and try to track user property by advertising identifier. But now I also use appInstanceId for app user identification.

I read the [official document](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6318039?hl=en) about tracking advertising identifier on Firebase and understand about what kind of data we can track.
But I don't understand about the difference of definition between appInstanceId.

- Are these two id generated in a different way? (I think advertising identifier is device-specific, while appInstanceId is app-specific. Is it true?)
- Can I track the advertising identifier itself on Firebase and check the value of it? (appInstanceId is automatically tracked, and we can export the value to BigQuery)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, advertising identifier is device specific. If you have 2 apps on the same device, they will report the same advertising identifier unless the user set limit ad tracking to true on their iOS device. App instance ID is unique among apps on the same device, and it doesn't depend on the advertising identifier. On iOS, you can get it yourself using [AdSupport](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/adsupport) framework. Firebase console doesn't show you the raw data of IDFA so you might want to track it using custom user property and query it using Big Query.